# IEnumerable of Custom class and String.Join()

Tags: c#, collections, tostring

I've created a class which acts as an all-purpose DataType class. I am doing this because I need to serialize a collection of misc-typed objects to JSON, and I'd like to be able to create the full data set as a collection. Like so:

```
JSON.Serialize(new []
{
    new Chameleon("aDate", DateTime.Now),
    new Chameleon("aString", "FUBAR")
});
```

The following is a simplified version of my implementation:

```
class Chameleon
{
    private String _type;
    private String _key;
    private Object _value;

    public Chameleon(String key, String value)
    {
        _type = "string";
        _key = key;
        _value = value;
    }

    public Chameleon(String key, DateTime value)
    {
        _type = "string";
        _key = key;
        _value = value;
    }

    public new String ToString()
    {
        // returns internal data, formatted data according to _type
    }
}
```

This is all well and good, but when I try and join - or concatinate if you will - a collection of Chameleon using `String.Join()`, `ToString()` on Chameleon objects in the collection are not called by the `String.Join()` method; instead I get the usual namespace + class-name string returned.

Why is `String.Join()` not calling my custom `ToString()` implementation? What am I missing?

Here's what I'm doing:

```
JSON.Serialize(String.Join<Chameleon>(",", new []
{
    new Chameleon("aDate", DateTime.Now),
    new Chameleon("aString", "FUBAR")
}));
```

Comment: I haven't tried your example yet, but have you tried creating your ToString method as override rather than as "new"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that this occurs because you define `ToString` as a `new` method, rather than overriding it.  Try this code instead:

```
public override String ToString()
{
    // returns internal data, formatted data according to _type
}
```

Comment: @roosteronacid, glad it worked for you.  I'd generally suggest you avoid using `new` methods unless you have a good reason to do so.

Answer (score 2):

That was it.  Try defining your ToString like this:

```
  public override String ToString() //Note the override rather than new
  {
    //Format your string etc.
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `ToString` on each `Chameleon` object otherwise you have an array of `Chameleon` object instead of an array of `string` which should be used.

Comment: @Drew: You're totally right, and I see you provided the correct answer :).